# keep blanks from a flat file SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

How to keep blank values intact from a text file source in SSIS. There is an integer column with blank values.

When I do a straight import with no derived column I get 0's instead of blanks. If I use the expression below I get NULL's

```
(DT_STR,10,1252)intcol == "" ? (DT_STR,10,1252)"" : (DT_STR,10,1252)intcol
```

How to load data as is from the source file into the staging table using SSIS.

Comment: How is the destination defined? Is this a text file or a database table?

Comment: You cannot load a blank string into an integer field in a table, if that's what you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a check box on source in DF to check to keep nulls. Weird stuff happens with dates as well.

This should be default but you will never forget to look again!